# In elisp is there a difference between the regex [\\]documentclass and \\documentclass?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was playing around with the **rx** function for generating regular expressions from **sexps** in **ELISP** but couldn't figure out how to generate the regular expression *"\\documentclass"* for use in org-export-latex-classes:

```
    (rx "\\documentclass")
    (rx "\\" "documentclass")
    (rx (char "\\") "documentclass")
```

Which when evaluated give respectively the following outputs:

```
    "\\\\documentclass"
    "\\\\documentclass"
    "[\\]documentclass"
```

Is *"\\documentclass"* equivalent to *"[\\]documentclass"*?---I think it is, but am not sure. Can I generate the former using rx?

Edit: Whilst the question was valid I realize my motivation was not; because org-export-latex-classes use strings not regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs requires `\` to be escaped in the double-quoted *read syntax* for strings and so, when the code is processed by the *lisp reader*, `"\\"` evaluates to a string *object* containing a single `\` character; and hence that single backslash is what the regexp engine sees when it uses that string object.

However, a `\` in a regexp *also* has an escaping function, which means that the sequence `\\` in a regexp matches a single `\`.

To represent the sequence `\\` in (the read syntax for) Emacs strings, each of those backslashes must itself be escaped by prefixing it with a backslash.

Therefore `"\\\\"` evaluates to a string containing `\\` which can be used as a regexp matching a single `\`.

Within a regexp *character alternative* sequence, however, backslashes are not escaped; and so `[\]`, represented by the string `"[\\]"`, matches a single backslash -- the only possible match for that single-character set.

So used as regexps, the strings `"\\\\"` and `"[\\]"` match the same thing.

The string `"\\documentclass"` as a regexp is effectively the same as `"documentclass"` with no backslashes at all, as it is the `d` which is being escaped in the regexp (which is valid, but of course unnecessary).

The elisp manual explains this as follows:

```
`\' has two functions: it quotes the special characters (including
`\'), and it introduces additional special constructs.

Because `\' quotes special characters, `\$' is a regular
expression that matches only `$', and `\[' is a regular expression
that matches only `[', and so on.

Note that `\' also has special meaning in the read syntax of Lisp
strings (*note String Type::), and must be quoted with `\'.  For
example, the regular expression that matches the `\' character is
`\\'.  To write a Lisp string that contains the characters `\\',
Lisp syntax requires you to quote each `\' with another `\'.
Therefore, the read syntax for a regular expression matching `\'
is `"\\\\"'.

[...]

As a `\' is not special inside a character alternative, it can never
remove the special meaning of `-' or `]'.  So you should not quote
these characters when they have no special meaning either.  This would
not clarify anything, since backslashes can legitimately precede these
characters where they _have_ special meaning, as in `[^\]' (`"[^\\]"'
for Lisp string syntax), which matches any single character except a
backslash.
```

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Regexp Special` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thanks that clarifies things. I was trying to generate the strings using **rx** in **org-export-latex-classes** and interpreting them as reg expressions similar to those I generated for **auto-mode-alist** but now I see clearly they are not.